# Kendo multi level bar chart issue zoom issue

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-chart

I generated the chart with kendo

**Its 2 level's of chart**.

**[Here is the js fiddle with 2 level's of chart](https://jsfiddle.net/prasadraja07/ug0w5ebq/4/)**

Issue was, when zoom the chart with the help of **pan & zoom** in kendo chart grid lines shows mismatch.

**Actual image after generating chart.**

[image]

**After applying pan & zoom**
[image]

**Actually this what i am looking for...Kendo is not showing correct location**
[image]

```
jQuery("#chart").kendoChart({
"chartArea": {
    "height": 500
},
"title": {
    "text": "Working women in Bahrain"
},
"legend": {
    "labels": {
        "template": "#= series.name #"
    },
    "position": "top"
},
"series": [{
    "name": "Divorced",
    "type": "column",
    "data": [85393, 77464, 96399, 83679, 115378, 96117, 81731, 77118, 86773, 89057, 101897, 81349],

    "stack": false
}, {
    "name": "Married",
    "type": "column",
    "data": [77220, 85787, 94838, 92456, 93399, 89375, 79801, 87342, 105411, 100824, 94300, 92005],        
    "stack": false
}, {
    "name": "Single",
    "type": "column",
    "data": [102443, 91787, 100185, 86968, 99938, 104390, 102129, 98333, 92575, 69093, 88107, 84893],        
    "stack": false
}, {
    "name": "Widow",
    "type": "column",
    "data": [97150, 85356, 97143, 95212, 97313, 93572, 87118, 91988, 103927, 91054, 93480, 90099],        
    "stack": false
}],
"categoryAxis": [{
    "labels": {
        "rotation": {
            "angle": "auto"
        }
    },
    "majorGridLines": {
        "visible": false
    },
    "title": {
        "text": "Sectors",
        "position": "left"
    },
    "categories": ["Private", "Public", "Private", "Public", "Private", "Public", "Private", "Public", "Private", "Public", "Private", "Public"]
}, {
    "labels": {
        "rotation": {
            "angle": "auto"
        }
    },
    "majorGridLines": {
        "visible": true
    },
    "line": {
        "visible": true
    },
    "title": {
        "text": "Year",
        "position": "left"
    },
    "categories": ["2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015"]
}],
"valueAxis": [{
    "majorGridLines": {
        "visible": false
    }
}],    
"tooltip": {
    "format": "{0}%",
    "template": "#= series.name #: #= value #",
    "visible": true
},
"pannable": {
    "lock": "y"
},
"zoomable": {
    "mousewheel": {
        "lock": "y"
    },
    "selection": {
        "lock": "y"
    }


  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

May not be exactly what you want, but for the years axis,make sure you have the same number of categories as the sector axis by having each year twice. Then use the **[step property](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#configuration-categoryAxis.majorTicks.step)** for labels, majorTicks, and majorGridLines:

```
{
    "labels": {
        "rotation": {
            "angle": "auto"
        },
        step: 2
    },
    "majorGridLines": {
        "visible": true,
        color: "black",
        step: 2
    },
    majorTicks: {
        step: 2
    },
    "line": {
        "visible": true
    },
    "title": {
        "text": "Year",
        "position": "left"
    },
    "categories": ["2010", "2010","2011","2011", "2012","2012", "2013","2013", "2014","2014", "2015", "2015"]
}
```

## **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/ezanker/pen/grdyoR)**

Comment: @esanker when i was zoom the chart(With the help of pan & zoom) this this major grid lines was showing in wrong position... if you apply pan & zoom for this.... you can see the problem....

Comment: @PrasadRaja, With my changes the majorgridlines are now correct at any zoom level: http://codepen.io/ezanker/pen/grdyoR   Use your mousewheel to zoom in the codepen demo.

Comment: There was issue with the example(When you pan/zoom the chart, we have Major grid line according to the year regarding of public/private, it was mismatching when you drag/move the axis)...if you notice that  you can see the problem. Help will be appreciated.

Comment: @PrasadRaja, for me when I run my example in codepen, the issue is resolved.  Are you still seeing the issue in the codepen? If so, on what browser?

Comment: The issue was (When you pan/zoom the chart, we have Major grid line according to the year regarding of public/private, Major grid line mismatching when you drag/move the axis) ... did you notice that ? (Chromer Browser)

Comment: @PrasadRaja, with your original code I noticed the problem. With my changes in the codepen, I no longer see the problem (also Chrome).  So you still see the problem in my codepen?

Comment: i created answer with more detail explanation... can you check it & reply

Answer (score 0):

@ezanker

**[Code Pen Demo](http://codepen.io/prasadraja07/pen/ZOqQWq/)**

http://codepen.io/prasadraja07/pen/ZOqQWq/

I created a another codepen for you to notify the issue with..

I have attached the image in stage level

**Generate Chart Level 1 **
[image]

**After Pan/Zoom**
[image]

**Issue image on zoom/Pan, Mismatch the Major grid lines**
[image]

```
    jQuery("#chart").kendoChart({
        "chartArea": {
            "height": 500
        },
        "title": {
            "text": "Testing"
        },
        "legend": {
            "labels": {
                "template": "#= series.name #"
            },
            "position": "top"
        },
        "series": [{
            "name": "Private",
            "type": "column",
            "data": [2647.67, 2273.22, 2685.17, 2455.22, 2506.39, 2603.03, 2790.78, 2893.28, 2722.17, 2807.06, 2894.61, 2854.72, 2122, 2883.83, 2384.44, 2353.58, 3053.56, 2350.03, 2822.92, 2570.33, 2679.78, 2398.89, 2685.22, 2730.11],
            "labels": {
                "visible": true
            },
            "stack": false
        }, {
            "name": "Public",
            "type": "column",
            "data": [2111.03, 2309.56, 2203.75, 2831.06, 2430.86, 2666.58, 2382.61, 2473.14, 2553.5, 2700, 2851.81, 2546.19, 2097.92, 2684.31, 2485.89, 2586.92, 2338.94, 2535.83, 2272.75, 2575.47, 2458.39, 2740.58, 2160.53, 2316.78],
            "labels": {
                "visible": true
            },
            "stack": false
        }],
        "categoryAxis": [{
            "labels": {
                "rotation": {
                    "angle": "auto"
                }
            },
            "majorGridLines": {
                "visible": false
            },
            "title": {
                "text": "Governorate",
                "position": "left"
            },
            "categories": [
                                                                "Category1", "Category2", "Category3", "Category4", "Category1", "Category2", "Category3", "Category4", "Category1", "Category2", "Category3", "Category4", "Category1", "Category2", "Category3", "Category4", "Category1", "Category2", "Category3", "Category4", "Category1", "Category2", "Category3", "Category4"]
        }, {
            "labels": {
                "visible": true,
                "step": 4,
                "rotation": {
                    "angle": "auto"
                }
            },
            "majorGridLines": {
                "width": 1,
                "step": 4,
                "color": "black",
                "visible": true
            },
            "title": {
                "text": "Year",
                "position": "left"
            },
            "majorTicks": {
                "step": 4
            },
            "categories": ["2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", "2011", "2011", "2011", "2011", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015"]
        }],
        "valueAxis": [{
            "majorGridLines": {
                "visible": false
            }
        }],
        "transitions": false,
        "tooltip": {
            "format": "{0}%",
            "template": "#= series.name #: #= value #",
            "visible": true
        },
        "pannable": {
            "lock": "y"
        },
        "zoomable": {
            "mousewheel": {
                "lock": "y"
            },
            "selection": {
                "lock": "y"
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I see it now. I think you should ask Telerik about this.